# Connect to H2 with IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, h2

H2 is used as a local database on desktop app.

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./h2-local-storage/data
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

I try to connect to DB with IntelliJ IDEA but can't catch what is database URL in connection settings.

[image]

I'm already try to use `h2-local-storage` and `data` and `h2-local-storage/data` and `./h2-local-storage/data` but noting to change. Always the same error:

> Connection is broken: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed
> out: localhost:9092" [90067-200]

I know about UI in the browser but I search the way to use IDEA for quick view. How to connect to this DB?

Answer (score 2):

please switch 'Connection type' to 'Embedded' (just click the link 'Remote'), then you'll be able to specify path to your database file.

Comment: `embeded` or `in-memory` worked for me. Thank you.